# ¿Cómo puedo manejar una fecha de caducidad en php?

Tags: php, date, textarea

Tengo un pequeño código que hace lo siguiente:

Tengo un campo que mando a llamar de la db que se llama: fecha_solicitud en el cual cuando lo lleno y pongo una fecha posterior a la actual, me pinta un mensaje que faltan 10 días para su caducidad.

Ejemplo si pongo la fecha posterior :

```
01-12-2020
```

Me dice que tengo 30 días para vencimiento.

Lo que busco que es cuando ponga la fecha actual

```
01-11-2020
```

en automático me diga que son 30 días de vencimiento

mi código es el siguiente:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fecha = date('Y-m-d');

$fecha_inicio = date_create($fecha);

$fecha_final = date_create($row['fecha_solicitud']);

$cuenta_regresiva = date_diff($fecha_inicio,$fecha_final);

 echo'<td><span class="label label-default"> Faltan' . $cuenta_regresiva ->d.  " 

 <br>días para su vencimiento <br> del pedido ";
```

Comment: Crea la fecha de vencimiento basado en la solicitud y agrega 30 días con [`date_add()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php), luego comparas la fecha actual con la de vencimiento.

Comment: No sé si entendí bien, pero buscas tomas la fecha `fecha_solicitud` sumarle 30 días y calcular la diferencia con la fecha actual? Igual que utilizas date_diff puedes utilizar `date_add` para añadir una cantidad de tiempo. Cómo recomendación, la interfaz orientada a objetos de las clases de tiempo pueden simplificar tu código.

Comment: No entedí bien, quieres que salga un mensaje de warning cuando pongas la fecha igual a la actual y no permitir el ingreso de la fecha con 0 dias de caducidad?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes corregir los dias de vencimiento cuando es igual a la actual, para que el resto del script siga igual:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
$fecha_inicio = date_create($fecha);
$fecha_final = date_create($row['fecha_solicitud']);
$cuenta_regresiva = date_diff($fecha_inicio,$fecha_final);
$days = $cuenta_regresiva->d;
if ($days==0){
   $days = 30;
 }
echo'<td><span class="label label-default"> Faltan' . $days .  " 
  <br>días para su vencimiento <br> del pedido ";
```

Comment: Muchas amigo, la verdad ya andaba un poco bloqueado me ha servidor de mucho, ya solo reste días para que conforme vayan avanzando se vayan descontando.
Saludos.